# scons does not find LaTeX DVI builder

Tags: latex, scons

I installed MacTex-2009 (from http://www.tug.org/mactex/2009/) and scons (1.2.0) on my iMac running Snow Leopard. Then I tested the installation with a trivial SConstruct file:

```
    env = Environment()
    dvi = env.DVI(target="hello.dvi",source="hello.tex")
```

and an obvious LaTeX "hello.tex" file.  When I execute "scons", I get:

```
    scons: Reading SConscript files ...
    AttributeError: SConsEnvironment instance has no attribute 'DVI':
      File "/Users/tsf/temp/SConstruct", line 2:
        dvi = env.DVI(target="hello.dvi",source="hello.tex")
```

After the first line I added the command:

```
    print str(env["BUILDERS"])
```

and I could see that the DVI builder does not appear.  I am using the same files on a Linux machine (different TeX installation) and it works.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem already. It seems that scons does not find MacTex-2009, so that the SConstruct file should look like:

```
    import os
    env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
    dvi = env.DVI(target="hello.dvi",source="hello.tex")
```

Now it works!

-- Tsf